# Jest with Vue3 ERROR: Cannot destructure property 'config' of 'undefined' as it is undefined

Tags: jestjs, vuejs3, laravel-mix-vue3

Please could yo help with the next error, I tried to create my tests in VUE3 with Jest but I have the next error, I'm using laravel 8 with webpack mix

Any idea?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRmHz.png)

Comment: Did you ever figure out a fix for this? I'm running into the same issue after upgrading to React.v17 and Jest.v27.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue.

Answer (score 4):

On the project, I used Vue3, Vite, Typescript and testing tool Jest. I found only 1 solution to fix this. I have the same issue and spent few hours finding the correct answer. You can try to change the version of Jest from ^27 to ^26 in package.json.

```
"jest": "^26.6.3"
```

If you use Typescript too, you should change the version of the ts-jest plugin.

```
"ts-jest": "^26.5.6"
```